# Magento 2.4 Varnish error 503

Tags: magento2, cache, varnish, server-setup

I got a copy of my Magento in another server, all checked permissions, vanilla installation, domain, but I don't find the issue, I keep seeing this error message below.

```
Error 503 Backend fetch failed
Backend fetch failed
```

I found this reference from Magento but didn't work.

https://support.magento.com/hc/en-us/articles/360034631211-Troubleshooting-503-errors

I'm sure the issue is in these lines below, when I removed them, it worked, but I know I need it to not serving content while PHP is down.

`/etc/varnish/default.vcl`.

[image: magento2 Error 503 Backend fetch failed]

How could I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Assumptions

This entire answer is based on the assumption that you didn't perform any specific *cache configuration* in `app/etc/env.php`

If this is not the case for you, the answer might be irrelevant.

### What is happening in Varnish

Varnish is returning an `HTTP/503`, not because it could not connect to the origin server, but because the health check fails. The backend became unhealthy because the URL it probes returns an `HTTP/500` error.

You can actually verify this by running `varnishlog -g raw -i Backend_health` as illustrated below:

```
root@varnish:/etc/varnish# varnishlog -g raw -i Backend_health
         0 Backend_health - boot.default Still sick 4---X-R- 1 5 10 0.122153 0.000000 HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
```

There's something wrong in `/pub/health_check.php`, and returns `HTTP/500` as a consequence. We need to fix this in Magento.

### What is happening in Magento

When you look in `var/log/debug.log`, you might see lines appearing that look as follows:

```
main.ERROR: Cache configuration is invalid
```

So `/pub/health_check.php` is failing because the cache configuration is faulty.

### Looking at the source code of the health check

When we look at the source code of `pub/health_check.php`, you'll see that the following if-statement contains an error that matches what we see in the log files:

```
if (!isset($cacheConfig[ConfigOptionsListConstants::CONFIG_PATH_BACKEND]) ||
!isset($cacheConfig[ConfigOptionsListConstants::CONFIG_PATH_BACKEND_OPTIONS])) {
    http_response_code(500);
    $logger->error("Cache configuration is invalid");
    exit(1);
}
```

> FYI: the constant `ConfigOptionsListConstants::CONFIG_PATH_BACKEND` is actually translated into `backend`, and `ConfigOptionsListConstants::CONFIG_PATH_BACKEND_OPTIONS` is translated into `backend_options`.

So what the health check is expecting is that your *cache configuration* contains the `backend` and `backend_options` keys.

### How to fix the issue

To fix the issue, simply update `app/etc/env.php` and add a caching backend, and potentially some backend options.

Here's how I configured it:

```
    'cache' => [
        'frontend' => [
            'default' => [
                'id_prefix' => '40d_',
                'backend'         => 'Cm_Cache_Backend_Redis',
                'backend_options' => [
                     'server' => '127.0.0.1',
                     'port'   => '6379',
                ]
            ],
        ]
    ],
```

> FYI: I installed *Redis* to make sure the `127.0.0.1:6379` endpoint actually exists. After that, Magento will store its internal cache objects inside *Redis*.

Any other cache configuration in addition to the `default` key should also have a `backend` defined, and some `backend_options`.

If the page cache configuration gets in your way, simply delete it, because *Varnish* is going to be your page cache.

### You're all set

After the cache config is finalized, `/pub/health_check.php` will no longer complain.

If you then run `varnishlog -g raw -i Backend_health` again, you'll get the following output:

```
0 Backend_health - boot.default Still sick 4---X-RH 4 5 10 0.189570 0.199402 HTTP/1.1 200 OK
0 Backend_health - boot.default Back healthy 4---X-RH 5 5 10 0.348480 0.236672 HTTP/1.1 200 OK
0 Backend_health - boot.default Still healthy 4---X-RH 6 5 10 0.202581 0.228149 HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

You see that Varnish's health checks succeeded, and that the site is fully functional.

Comment: you are just amazing 